# Polar coordinate line to slope intercept form

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I'm finding it very difficult to find an answer on google and in my math book on this. The question give to us is:

A curve with polar equation

$$
r= \frac{39}{9\sin\theta+19\cos\theta}
$$

represents a line. This line has a Cartesian equation of the form
$y = mx + b$, where $m$ and $b$ are constants. Give the formula
for $y$ in terms of $x$. For example, if the line had equation
$y = 2x+3$ then the answer would be $2x + 3$.

I have tried to take the derivative of this equation to get $m$ and I have plugged in $0$ for $\theta$ in an attempt to get $b$. I originally did this by trying to convert $r$ to cartesian coordinates first by using $x = r\sin\theta$ and $y = r\cos\theta$, but with no success. We never covered this in class and I can't find any examples anywhere that have helped me answer this. Is there a process to follow when converting the entire equation from polar curves to cartesian equations?

Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$9r\sin\theta+19r\cos\theta=39\ .$$

Comment: Does this become Ax+By+C = 0 or is that way off? I tried multiplying the denominator on both sides like you did, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Actually, that makes a lot of sense now. Thank you!!!